# FFmpeg fade audio to volume

Tags: ffmpeg

I have say 5 segments of audio and i want to set each segment to a specific volume but when i concat the segments i'd like there to be a fade from previous volume to the next volume.

I see `afade` filter is for simply fading in/out. I see `acrossfade` which would more than likely be desirable except that the video the audio will play over will not be cross-faded.

I'm wondering if this can be done with something like `aeval` or if there are any good ideas out there.

Maybe someone can explain this filter function or where to learn about the syntax:

```
Fade volume after time 10 with an annihilation period of 5 seconds:
volume='if(lt(t,10),1,max(1-(t-10)/5,0))':eval=frame
```

Comment: You can use `acrossfade`. It won't fade the video.

Comment: The audio would get out of sync

Comment: If you're using the entire stream, they will, whichever method you use. If not, you have to extend the audio trim by half the duration of the crossfade.

Comment: Are you just looking for smooth volume change?

Comment: yes. just so it's not sudden from scene to scene

Comment: How about normalization post-concat?

Comment: Could you describe in an answer?

Comment: You can use the [dynaudnorm](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-all.html#dynaudnorm) filter to even out the volume over the course of the audio. You'll have to experiment with the parameters, esp. enable RMS and set it some non-zero value.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I realized i can use `afade` and just manipulate the start time of the fade by calculating the time it takes to fade out to the next volume on a linear scale.

So to fade to 50% volume on a 15 second video, i would do something like

```
afade=t=out:st=14:d=2
```

Meaning i start a 2 second linear fade with 1 second left of audio, therefor leaving it at 50% volume on finish.

Comment: What if it's not on the end of the video ;)

Comment: Here are the docs for `afade` for others wondering what the param options are/mean: https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#toc-afade-1